# In the following reaction, will the ratio between substances be 3:1?

Tags: equilibrium

In the reaction 
$$\ce{3 C2H2(g) <=> C6H6(g)}$$
will the ratio of $\ce{[C2H2(g)]}$ to $\ce{[C6H6(g)]}$ at equilibrium be 3:1?

How is the mole ratio related to the equilibrium (or lack thereof) of the reaction? How do I know if 3:1 is indeed the ratio?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The location of the equilibrium is dependent on many factors, most prominently temperature and pressure.

A [chemical equilibrium](http://goldbook.iupac.org/C01023.html) appears to have a static composition, which is of course not true. The point in question is where the rates of the reaction equal in both directions. The equilibrium can be described by the [equilibrium constant](http://goldbook.iupac.org/E02177.html) $K$, which is defined as the product of partial pressure $p_{\ce{B}}$, concentration $c_{\ce{B}}$, [...], chemical activity $a_{\ce{B}}$, in general $x_{\ce{B}}$ of the reactants and products, with respect to their stoichiometric number $\nu_{\ce{B}}$.
$$ K_x = \prod_{\ce{B}}(x_{\ce{B}})^{\nu_{\ce{B}}}$$
The standard equilibrium constant $K^\circ$ is given through the standard reaction Gibbs energy $\Delta_r G^\circ$ and the thermodynamic temperature $T$, $\mathcal{R}$ is the gas constant.
$$K^\circ = \exp\left\{\frac{-\Delta_r G^\circ}{\mathcal{R}\cdot T}\right\}$$
Since all equilibrium constants are proportional to each other it follows for a constant temperature, $T = \mathrm{const.}$, that the location is dependent on the Gibbs energy:
$$ \prod_{\ce{B}}(x_{\ce{B}})^{\nu_{\ce{B}}} \propto \exp\left\{-\Delta_r G^\circ\right\}$$

---

In your case $$\ce{3 C2H2(g) <=> C6H6(g)}$$ you would probably choose a pressure based approach $$K_p = \frac{p(\ce{C6H6})}{p^3(\ce{C2H2})} \propto \exp\left\{-\Delta_r G^\circ\right\}$$

And you can see the temperature and pressure dependency in the [original definition](http://goldbook.iupac.org/G02629.html):
\begin{align}
G(p,T) &= H - TS\\
H(p,T) &= U + pV\\
\end{align}

So you will only know the product ratio by very accurate calculations or empirical measurement.

For the system in question, I believe it has been done and the results may be found in [W. J. Taylor, *et. al.*, J. Res. Natl. Bur. Stand., Vol. 37, No. 2, p. 95](https://ia601508.us.archive.org/21/items/jresv37n2p95/jresv37n2p95_A1b.pdf).